How to programmatically extract JS inserted styling for entire page?
I need to mimic the 'Save Webpage Complete' functionality in javascript.
I'm using Azure Bot webchat UI framework, and have a use case where I want to save a rendered webpage. I am able to extract all the rendered HTML as well as inline css from all css files directly referenced in the page. But a lot of styling is added by webchat.js library and I'm not sure how to extract it programmatically (in JS).
When I inspect the element, I see the style, but when I try navigating to it, it disappears!

I verified this comes from webchat.js:


This is not as easy as it may look.
From JavaScript, you will likely hit CORS protection, such as:

Uncaught DOMException: CSSStyleSheet.rules getter: Not allowed to
access cross-origin stylesheet

To retrieve the computed styling, while it is not that useful, you might find interesting details in there.
{...window.getComputedStyle(document.body)}

To extract the whole CSS, if CORS is allowed in the context, you could try:
[...document.styleSheets].forEach((t) => {
      [...t.rules].forEach((t) => {
            console.log(t)
      })
})

For example, the above script won't run on Stackoverflow, but is running on websites such as Wikipedia.
Source, with more reading:
RePack bookmarklet. Dump static page in one HTML file
